# SQLite- Check Condition to match records with same condition?

Tags: sqlite

Say I have this table I built in SQLiteStudio

```
|ID|VAL|STRATEGY|
|1 |A  |LOWEST  |
|2 |A  |LOWEST  |
|3 |B  |PRIORITY|
|4 |B  |PRIORITY|
|5 |C  |LOWEST  |
```

The only valid values for STRATEGY are `LOWEST` and `PRIORITY` so I set this check condition for it.

```
STRATEGY IN ('LOWEST','PRIORITY')
```

If I update the record with ID 1 to be `PRIORITY`, I want it to fail because I want both records of VALUE A to be `PRIORITY`. All records with a common `VALUE` should be on the same `STRATEGY`.

```
UPDATE STRATEGY_MAP SET STRATEGY = 'PRIORITY' WHERE ID = 1 /* This should fail*/
```

So if I were to update both records, then everything would validate fine.

```
UPDATE STRATEGY_MAP SET STRATEGY = 'PRIORITY' WHERE ID in (1,2)
```

***OR...***

```
UPDATE STRATEGY_MAP SET STRATEGY = 'PRIORITY' WHERE VAL = 'A'
```

Is there an easy way to add this validation in SQLite with my earlier one? I know it could probably be pulled off with triggers in MySQL. But I'd like my SQLite prototype database to enforce this rule.

Comment: There are triggers in sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: If your `VAL`/`STRATEGY`s can only occur in matched sets, then that's probably telling you that you should have two tables: one listing `ID`s and `VAL`s and another holding the `PRIORITY` for each `VAL` and join on `VAL` as needed.

Comment: Yeah I could normalize it that way. But the way the business manages its parameters, this would be much easier for parameter entry. Sometimes over-normalization makes parameter input tedious.

Comment: Possibly `UPDATE STRATEGY_MAP SET STRATEGY = 'PRIORITY' WHERE VAL = ( SELECT VAL FROM STRATEGY_MAP WHERE ID = 1 )` will keep things in sync without having to know the list of IDs for the `IN` clause and only driven by an `ID` to update?

Comment: Constraints and triggers are evaluated after changing each row, so the intermediate steps would fail.

Comment: Man I was just wondering about that. Dang it.